# How to use fields_for for child update in 1-to-many in rails 3.1.3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

A user has many user_levels and a user_level belongs to a user. Here is the code for user_level for update:

```
<%= simple_form_for @user do |f| %>
  <% @user.user_levels.each do |level| %>    
    <%= f.fields_for :user_levels, level do |builder| %>
      <p><%= render :partial => 'user_levels', :locals => {:f => builder, :i_id => level.position} %></p>  
    <% end %> 
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The code above will display the current user_level with selected set to the current position. The problem is that the update was not saved for user_level.

Here is the user_levels partial

```
<div class="fields">
  <%= f.input :position, :collection => return_position, :prompt => "Choose position", 
                      :label => false, :include_blank => true, :selected => i_id %>
  <%= link_to_remove_fields "remove", f %>
</div>
```

Here is the string posted to the server for params[:user]. There are currently two positions for the user and one gets deleted as update:

```
{"name"=>"test eng", "login"=>"tester12", "password"=>"password", "password_confirmation"=>"password", "user_type"=>"employee", "user_levels_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"id"=>"5"}, "1"=>{"position"=>"elec_eng", "_destroy"=>"false", "id"=>"6"}}}
```

Any solution for child update? Thanks so much

UPDATE:

```
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    @user.input_by_id = session[:user_id]
    if @user.save!
      redirect_to URI.escape("/view_handler?index=0&msg=saved！")
    else
      flash.now[:error] = 'not saved！'
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.input_by_id = session[:user_id]
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      redirect_to URI.escape("/view_handler?index=0&msg=saved}")
    else
      flash.now[:error] = 'not saved！'
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
```

user.rb:

```
  has_many :user_levels, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_levels, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:position].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true
  validates_associated :user_levels
```

Comment: Just figured out that the code is correct. However code to delete the record completely is not correct.

Comment: By record, do you mean user or user level ? With the `:dependent => :destroy` option, when you delete a user, its user levels are destroyed too. Its pretty straightforward. Or, if you want to have a delete user level option when editing a user, you'll need to pass the `_destroy` option for user level. The params hash to delete a user level should look somewhat like `params = { :user => {:user_levels_attributes => [{ :id => '1', :_destroy => '1'}]} }`.
p.s. I don't think `validates_associated` is required, since nested attributes will validate the user levels too. However, please confirm this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the line `@user.user_levels.each do |level|` and please post what issue pops up then.
And does the user model accept nested attributes for user levels ?

Comment: After removing .each, the user level still could not be saved. The string posted is: {"name"=>"test eng", "login"=>"tester12", "password"=>"password", "password_confirmation"=>"password", "user_type"=>"employee", "user_levels_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"id"=>"5"}, "1"=>{"position"=>"", "_destroy"=>"false", "id"=>"6"}}}. The string is the same as before removing. But the position was not carried into partial and current value was not retained.

Comment: Do you have `accept nested attributes for` user levels on user model ? The params hash seems to be alright, except, as you say, the position on second user level object is empty. If you want to update user levels when updating user, you'll need to include that. Check if this works.
If it doesn't, can you post a snippet of user model and user#create and user#update.

Comment: accept_nested_attributes_for in user.rb. new/create has no problem. Now we are working on update.

Comment: Just verified that the code is correct for update. however the code for delete is not working. Thanks for the comments.